# Error on docker run

Tags: docker

i'm having a problem when i do docker run on a image that i created using this dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /Saiph
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
COPY . /Saiph
RUN npm install
```

The error is this:

```
PS D:\saiph> docker run 1ba8ca0d9b3b
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle saiph@1.0.0~prestart: saiph@1.
npm info lifecycle saiph@1.0.0~start: saiph@1.0.0

> saiph@1.0.0 start /Saiph
> cd server && node server

sh: 1: cd: can't cd to server
npm info lifecycle saiph@1.0.0~start: Failed to e
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! saiph@1.0.0 start: `cd server && node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the saiph@1.0.0 start script.
```

I've tried to understand the error but i didn't understand it, 
Sorry about my bad english,

Thanks

Comment: Change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`. And then build the image. Use `docker run <imageid> ls -al`. See if there is a server folder or not and if not then you know your answer why it is not working

Comment: I forgot to write that i'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is the difference between Windows and Linux file system. In windows if a folder named `Server` exists then you can use `cd server` or `cd Server` and it would work.

Linux is case sensitive. So either change your script to use the specific case or rename the folder from `Server` to `server`. You will need to do the same thing in code also to rename requires and other file related things to exact case

Answer (score 0):

@TarunLalwani

```
PS D:\seith> docker run 15027498053c ls -al
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Sep  9 19:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Sep  9 19:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Sep  9 00:41 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  6222 Sep  9 00:40 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Sep  9 16:29 .vs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep  8 22:55 Client
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep  9 00:38 Database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    92 Sep  9 19:15 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1089 Sep  9 00:37 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep  9 00:38 Server
drwxr-xr-x 76 root root  4096 Sep  9 16:29 node_modules
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 18807 Sep  9 19:15 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   368 Sep  9 16:29 package.json
```